# Override a translation on the Sonata Admin login screen

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.3, sonata-admin, sonata

On the Sonata Admin login screen the default translation is "Authentication", but i'd like to be able to change this.

Inside `\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\views\Admin\Security\login.html.twig` there is this line:

`<div class="header">{{ 'title_user_authentication'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}</div>`

The translation for this is found in `\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\translations\SonataUserBundle.en.xliff`, i.e.:

```
        <trans-unit id="title_user_authentication">
            <source>title_user_authentication</source>
            <target>Authentication</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

I am trying to work out how I can change this from within my own bundles. This scenario doesn't appear to be covered in the Sonata documentation, which is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding translations is not specific to Sonata, but to Symfony.

See the "Overriding any part of a bundle" section of the symfony doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#translations

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I read on the cookbook that the translations in `app/Resources/translations` "always wins". I just added a `SonataUserBundle.en.xliff` in there with my updated translation and it pulled through.